# Backwards compatibility when changing Spring Boot externalized configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, backwards-compatibility, spring-boot-configuration

Is there a recommended way to introduce restructurings/renamings into an externalized configuration while keeping backwards compatibility for consumers still relying on the old configuration structure?

For example, given a library used the following configuration structure defined via `@ConfigurationProperties` in the past:

```yaml
old-properties:
  an:
    old-property: true
  another:
    custom-property: 1234
```

A new version of that library redefines the configuration to something like this:

```yaml
my-library:
  a-property: true
  another-property: 1234
```

Is there a good way to deprecate the old structure while keeping compatibility for existing consumers for some time? Consumers using the new version of the library should still be able to use `old-properties.an.old-property` and have that automatically mapped to `my-library.a-property`.

I'm aware of the functionality to use [additional configuration metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html) to mark a property as deprecated, but I'm explicitly looking for a way to support both versions to ease migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into how Spring Boot handled the [deprecation phase for `logging.file`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/15089) (which was replaced by `logging.file.name`) and as they implemented the fallback directly in code I decided to try something similar by creating the new `@ConfigurationProperties` in a `@Bean` method which handles setting the values from old property names if available.

Given the new configuration structure looks like this (using Lombok for brevity):

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class MyLibraryConfigurationProperties {

    private String aProperty;
    private String anotherProperty;

}
```

The `@Bean` method now takes care of reading the old value and applying it to the properties:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
public class MyLibraryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-library")
    public MyLibraryConfigurationProperties myLibraryConfigurationProperties(Environment environment) {
        MyLibraryConfigurationProperties config = new MyLibraryConfigurationProperties();

        // fallback to old property if available
        if (environment.containsProperty("old-properties.an.old-property")) {
            // here we could also log warnings regarding the deprecation
            config.setAProperty(environment.getProperty("old-properties.an.old-property"));
        }

        return config;
    }
}
```

If the new value is also set via config, it will override the value set from the old property.

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot Configuration Processor provides a [`@DeprecatedConfigurationProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/DeprecatedConfigurationProperty.html) annotation for this purpose. The generated metadata file will include any reason/replacement notes, which causes appropriate deprecation warnings to be logged if an annotated property is used.

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/9aa1b528dff6463c40d53a0f1040b2c6c8dcce10/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-configuration-processor/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/configurationsample/simple/DeprecatedSingleProperty.java#L32-L41) for a basic example. The following snippet from [CassandraProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/9aa1b528dff6463c40d53a0f1040b2c6c8dcce10/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraProperties.java#L116-L133) shows a real-world use case in which `spring.data.cassandra.cluster-name` was deprecated in favor of `spring.data.cassandra.session-name`. Backwards compatibility is handled by simply calling the getter/setter for the replacement property in the getter/setter for the deprecated property:

```java
public String getSessionName() {
    return this.sessionName;
}

public void setSessionName(String sessionName) {
    this.sessionName = sessionName;
}

@Deprecated
@DeprecatedConfigurationProperty(replacement = "spring.data.cassandra.session-name")
public String getClusterName() {
    return getSessionName();
}

@Deprecated
public void setClusterName(String clusterName) {
    setSessionName(clusterName);
}
```

To achieve the same behavior for properties that aren't mapped to a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean you can manually specify them in `META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` and add a runtime dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator`. See [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-additional-metadata) for reference.

The following snippet from [spring-boot-autoconfigure](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/9aa1b528dff6463c40d53a0f1040b2c6c8dcce10/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json#L152-L160) shows a real-world use case in which `server.servlet.path` was deprecated in favor of `spring.mvc.servlet.path`. Backwards compatibility is handled by the [PropertiesMigrationListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/9aa1b528dff6463c40d53a0f1040b2c6c8dcce10/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-properties-migrator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/migrator/PropertiesMigrationListener.java), which *"Automatically renames the keys that have a matching replacement and log[s] a report of what was discovered."*:

```json
    {
      "name": "server.servlet.path",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "Path of the main dispatcher servlet.",
      "defaultValue": "/",
      "deprecation": {
        "replacement": "spring.mvc.servlet.path",
        "level": "error"
      }
    },
```

If you set the deprecated property `server.servlet.path=/foo`, the replacement property `@Value("${spring.mvc.servlet.path}")` will evaluate to `/foo`, and the deprecation notice will be logged on startup.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm aware (and already using) the additional metadata to mark those properties as deprecated and that my concern is only supporting both versions for some time to ease migration. Thanks for the hint with `@DeprecatedConfigurationProperty`, I was only aware of the `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` way.